# What is the difference between "NVIDIA driver metapackage" and "NVIDIA binary Xorg driver"?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I am running Gnome Desktop 3.36.3 on X11 11 (X.org version 1.20.8) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a ThinkPadP72 with an NVIDIA Quadro P4200.

I notice in Software & Updates > Additional Drivers that I am running the NVIDIA Driver Metapackage from nvidia-driver-450. However, I notice in apt-cache that there is also an NVIDIA binary Xorg driver from `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450`.

Is `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450` an official NVIDIA package, or is it a FOSS package?

If `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450` *is* an official NVIDIA package, when should one prefer it to `nvidia-driver-450`?